# Does the number of elements of order $r$ equal $\sum_{|x| = r} |x^G|$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to know if this sentence is true or not?

> Let $m_r$ be the number of elements of order $r$ in a finite group $G$ and also let $x$ be an element of order $r$ in this group, then  $m_r=\sum_{|x|=r}|x^G|$

where $|x|$ is the order of $x$ in $G$ and $x^G$ is the conjugacy class of $x$.

Comment: What is $|x|$ in your notation?

Comment: Is $\;x^g\;$ the conjugacy class of $\;x\;$ ? Because it can also mean it is the normal closure of $\;x\;$ .

Comment: $|x|$ is order of $x$ and $x^G$ is conjugacy class of $x$.

Comment: @Timbuc I think $x^G$ is standard for conjugacy class. The normal closure of $x$ is denoted by $\langle x^G \rangle$ or $\langle x \rangle^G$. I prefer $\langle x^G \rangle $ because that is unambiguous, whereas $\langle x \rangle^G$ could also denote the set of subgroups that are conjugate to $\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: I think you're right, @DerekHolt . Thanks.

Comment: It is not quite right as written. In the summation, you need to take one representative $x$ from each conjugacy class of elements of order $r$ in the case of non-Abelian groups, or else you will overcount.

Answer (score 0):

$$G=A_4\;,\;\;r=2\;,\;\;m_3=3$$

The elements of order $\;2\;$ here are $\;(12)(34)\,,\,\,(13)(24)\,,\,\,(14)(23)\;$ , and the conjugacy class of each of them is three as these elements, together with the unit element, for a *normal* subgroup of order four in $\;A_4\;$ , but then

$$\sum_{|x|=2}|x^G|=3+3+3=9\neq3=m_2$$

If $\;x^G\;$ means the normal closure the inequality above is, of course, even worse.